# Swipe tabs in dynamic fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dynamic, swipe

I wanted to implement swipe tabs in a dynamically generated fragment(it has no layout file) and I don't know how. I have tried something, reaching some "results", by that i mean that is shows me the tab layout, but it does not "load" the fragments. I suspect the problem is with the view pager, at the declaration.Here is the code for the fragment:

```
public class fg_tabs extends Fragment {

LinearLayout root;

TabLayout tab_layout;
ViewPager view_pager;
PagerAdapter pager_adaper;

public fg_tabs() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    root = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    tab_layout = new TabLayout(getActivity());
    view_pager = new ViewPager(getActivity());
    view_pager.setCurrentItem(2);

    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Penguins"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("North Wind"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Dr Octavious Brine"));


    tab_layout.setTabGravity(Gravity.FILL);
    pager_adaper = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),tab_layout.getTabCount());

    view_pager.setAdapter(pager_adaper);
    view_pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab_layout));

    tab_layout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    root.addView(tab_layout);
    return root;
}
```

}

and you maybe want to take a look at how i call this fragment, see if something is wrong there:

```
    fg_tabs tabs = new fg_tabs();
    FragmentManager fm= getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_frame,tabs).commit();
```

the pager adapter class:

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int n;

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int n) {
    super(fm);
    this.n=n;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position == 0)
        return new Penguins();

    if(position == 1)
        return new NorthWind();

    if(position == 2)
        return new DrOctaviousBrine();

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return n;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add your `ViewPager` to the view in `onCreateView`:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
root.addView(view_pager, params);
return root;
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it gives me this error (in run, not a syntax error) : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: btw, i used: new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
root.addView(view_pager, params);

Comment: I tried this, the app is running but the fragments don't start:view_pager = new ViewPager(getActivity());
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,MATCH_PARENT);
        view_pager.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: That error doesn't seem to be related, maybe your other fragments are having trouble with findViewById. Other than that I assume the code works, right?

Comment: hmm, agree with that

Comment: You could try to ask a new question about the error and stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for the question, the problem was not setting the params for the viewpager and not giving him an id, and not adding it to the layout. For those who are struglling with the same question, just take the normal swipe tabs code(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcnT-3F-9JA) and keep in mind that you are using a dynamic fragment so you can't declare xml.

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class fg_tabs extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout root;
    TabLayout tab_layout;
    ViewPager view_pager;
    PagerAdapter pager_adapter;

    public fg_tabs() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        root = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

        root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#42f4e8"));

        tab_layout = new TabLayout(getActivity());

        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("penguins"));
        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("north wind"));
        tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("octavious brine"));
        root.addView(tab_layout);

        tab_layout.setTabGravity(Gravity.FILL);

        view_pager = new ViewPager(getActivity());
        view_pager.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        view_pager.setId(View.generateViewId());
        root.addView(view_pager);

        pager_adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),tab_layout.getTabCount());

        view_pager.setAdapter(pager_adapter);
        view_pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab_layout));

        tab_layout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                view_pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```